# nodejs http request getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND error

Tags: jquery, firebase, https, xmlhttprequest, google-cloud-functions

I have try many way to make the http request but it always got the error `getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND`.

Environment: nodejs
Provider: Firebase Functions

**Method 1 - npm request**:

```
var options = {
     url: 'https://us-central1-<project>.cloudfunctions.net/api/wakeUp',
     headers: { "Authorization": "Basic password" }
 };

 function callback(error, response, body) {
     if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
       console.log(body)
     }
     console.log(error)
   }

   request(options, callback);
```

**Method 2 - npm jquery**:

```
$.ajax({
    headers:{"Authorization":"Basic password"},
    url: "https://us-central1-<project>.cloudfunctions.net/api/wakeUp",
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data)

    },
    error: function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
})
```

**Method 3 - npm https**:

```
var options = {
    url: 'us-central1-<project>.cloudfunctions.net',
    port: 443,
    path: '/api/wakeUp',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: { "Authorization": "Basic password" }
};

const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
    console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
    console.log('headers:', res.headers);

    res.on('data', (d) => {
        console.log(d)
    });
});

req.on('error', (e) => {
    console.error(e);
});
req.end();
```

Regardless which way, the console always show the error of `getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND :443`.

I really running out of idea, please advise.

*Side note:*

1) i masked the URL and Password from the request for privacy & security concern.

2) I have implemented the middleware to check the authorization. So if open the URL in browser it will say "unauthorized", but if i use Postman to send GET request with the header `"Authorization": "Basic password"`, it will show the API result as expected.

3) the API's code and the http request code is in the same firebase functions server/project.

4) the nodejs imported following  module, not sure is that causing some sort of conflict: `firebase-functions` , `firebase-admin`, `jsdom`, `request`, `https`, `express`, `body-parser`, `cors`, `jquery`, `nodemailer`

Comment: It seems target URL doesn't have `https` so its giving error `:443` please make sure URL have `https`

Comment: According to `https` documentation, seems like `Method 3 - npm https` doesn't allow to put "https" in the `url`. But the URL i want to call is definitely is using https because its google cloud function.

Comment: add `family: 4` in the options for `Method 3` and try with both `https` and `http` module.

Comment: also you can refer this URL: `https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/5436#issuecomment-373002246`

Comment: If you simply open the URL `https://us-central1-<project>.cloudfunctions.net/api/wakeUp` in a browser, what does it do?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have implemented the middleware to check the authorization. So if open the URL in browser it will say "unauthorized", but if i use Postman to send GET request with the header `"Authorization": "Basic password"`, it will show the API result as expected.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Side info, the API's code and the http request code is in the same firebase functions server/project.